# How to calculate the total area of multi vectors/shapefiles/polygons in each 1°×1° grid by python?

Tags: python, grid, gis, polygon, shapefile

I try to calculate the total area of the multi vectors in each grid, then each grid will have a only number to represent the shapefiles distribution in the gird. How to spilt the vectors which is across line and then calculate area of the left part (the other should be calculated in another gird) ?

Map:
[image]

Comment: by "each grid" do you mean "each grid cell"?

Comment: yes, each grid cell